# Twitter - Obtaining a request token : Code:32

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I wrote a function to get a request token from Twitter api. I am getting the below error

{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}

My code is like this

```
function beuTwitterOauthToken()
{   

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    $method = "POST";

    $oauth_callback = $this->beuTwitterApiCallBack;
    $oauth_consumer_key = $this->beuTwitterConsumerKey;
    $oauth_consumer_key_secret = $this->beuTwitterConsumerKeySecret;
    $oauth_nonce = $this->beuTwitterNonce();
    $oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_version = "1.0";

    $params = array(
        'oauth_callback'            =>  rawurlencode($oauth_callback),
        'oauth_consumer_key'        =>  rawurlencode($oauth_consumer_key),
        'oauth_nonce'               =>  rawurlencode($oauth_nonce),
        'oauth_signature_method'    => rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method),
        'oauth_timestamp'           =>  rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp),
        'oauth_version'             =>  rawurlencode($oauth_version)
    );

    ksort($params);

    $parameter_string = http_build_query($params);

    $base_string = $method . '&';
    $base_string .= rawurlencode($url) . '&';
    $base_string .= $parameter_string;

    $oauth_signing_key = rawurlencode($oauth_consumer_key_secret) . '&';
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_string, $oauth_signing_key, true));

    $params['oauth_signature'] = rawurlencode($oauth_signature);

    ksort($params);

        foreach($params as $key=>$value){
            $post .= $key.'='.'"'.$value.'", ';
        }

    $post = rtrim($post, ", ");

    $headers = array( 
        "POST /oauth/request_token HTTP/1.1",
        "User-Agent: Beu",
        "Host: api.twitter.com",
        "Accept: */*",          
        "Authorization: OAuth ". $post
    ); 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $retrievedhtml = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $retrievedhtml;

}
```

I cant figure out what is wrong with the code. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a problem with config parameters:

```
consumer_key & consumer_secret
```

I have two apps in twitter, one set for production environment and the one for development. I was mixing an access token retrieved in production environment, with the consumer key and secret provided for the application in development environment, thus they wouldn't match in twitter system.